# Cyclic carbocation rearrangement

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

Is there a way for the 4-methylcyclohexyl cation (4-methylcyclohex-1-ylium) to undergo some rearrangement and become tertiary carbocation via 1-3 or 1-4 shift?

[image: 4-methylcyclohex-1-ylium]

Comment: Ring contraction...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1,3- and 1,4- shifts don't really happen. It's just too far away. If you have a double bond at 4 or 5 carbons away, maybe you can do a ring closure or form a non-classical carbocation. The cation you've drawn could however undergo a sequence hydride shifts. Each hydride shift would move the cation closer to the methyl group, until the 3rd shift places the cation on the tertiary carbon. You'd need to out-compete any kind of elimination or cation reaction with a nucleophile...

Comment: Ok so though not impossible , but 1-3 or 1-4 would rarely happen right?

Comment: 1,3- and 1,4- are really weird. I doubt you'll ever get the stereoelectronics to line up for this. I've never seen an example (which, of course, doesn't mean it's impossible).